# Centering a ul with floats inside a div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center this bottom nav on a test site:

http://heroicdreams.com/kktest/

The ul li uses `float:left;` which is what I think is making it stay stuck to the left. I'm trying to figure out how to get it to be centered.

To get the links displayed horizontally I needed to float them left, but now I can't get the whole nav to be centered.  Is there a way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

often using:

```
.divStyle {
    text-align: center;
}
ul.styleName {
    margin: 0 auto; 
    text-align: left;
}
```

will do the trick.

Applying an "auto" margin to the left and right of the ul like this will cause it to center itself in the div whenever the div has centered text.  This is how many websites center the div that serves as the main content of their page.

Comment: Since you floated all of the list items, the ul is getting a height of zero and a width of 100%.

Comment: You could remove the display:inline on your ul, then make it have a fixed width (width: 500px) to center, though this is a bit of a hack because the ul isn't properly settings it's box width

Comment: the problem is that the width needs to be dynamic

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I solved it, and is for dynamically generated menus also.

Assume this is the dynamically generated menu:

```
<div id="menu">
   <ul>
      <li>One</li>
      <li>Two</li>
      <li>Three</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

and this is the CSS:

```
.menu {
    width:300px;
    text-align: center; /*Set a width and text-align on the main div*/
}

.menu ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    display:inline-block;
    list-style: none;   /*Set display to inline-block to the ul*/
}

.menu ul li {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1.3em; /*this is the usual*/
    padding: 0;
}
```

Now, for the list to be centered you need to add an empty paragraph to clear the float. You can do it manually if the menu is static or using `jQuery` like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("<p class='clear'></p>").insertAfter('.menu-header ul li:last-child');
})
```

and the CSS of the `.clear` paragraph will be:

```
p.clear{
    clear:both;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
}
```

and that's it!

Answer (score 1):

1. Add `style="text-align: center;"` to the parent div of the ul.
2. Add `style=" display:inline-table;"` to the ul.

Answer (score 0):

Either CSS:

```
margin: 0px auto;
```

or

```
/*on the nav's parent*/
text-align: center;

/*on the nav*/
text-align: left;
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for `margin:0 auto` to work, you need to set a width on your ul and remove the `display:inline`:

```
#footerLinks ul {
  list-style:none;
  margin:0 auto;
  padding:0;
  width:400px;
}
```

Comment: the problem is that the width needs to be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I think the KISS rule applies here:

```
ul { text-align: center; }
ul li { display: inline-block; }
```